# Groupby by Year with pd.Timestamp / dateTime64 in the format YYYY-MM-DD while keeping full timestamp

Tags: pandas, group-by, timestamp

I have a dataframe with a column "time" and "value" in the format YYYY-MM-DD and np.int64

```
time       | value
2009-11-03 | 13
2009-11-14 | 25
2009-12-05 | 25
2016-03-02 | 80
2016-05-17 | 56
```

I need to groupby by year, getting the maximum value by year. If days within the same year both have the highest value I need tp keep both. But I need to keep the full timestamp as well.

Desired output:

```
time       | value
2009-11-14 | 25
2009-12-05 | 25
2016-03-02 | 80
```

My code so far:

```
df["year"] = df["time"].dt.year
df = df.groupby(["year"], sort=False)['value'].max()
```

But this removes the timestamp and I only have the year + value as a column. How can I get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `transform` first then do filter

```
m=df.value.eq(df.groupby(df.time.dt.year).value.transform('max'))

df=df[m]
Out[111]: 
        time  value
1 2009-11-14     25
2 2009-12-05     25
3 2016-03-02     80
```

Comment: Can you please explain in detail what each step does? And how does the groupby keep duplicates if they have the same value?

Comment: @Vega transform is find the group max for each group, then we just need the value equal to max , that is the row we need

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the maximum values per year, and then join the result with the original data frame:

```
df["year"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"]).dt.year
max_val = df.groupby(["year"], sort=False)['value'].max()
pd.merge(max_val, df, on=["value", "year"])
```

result:

```
    value   year    time
0   25  2009    2009-11-14
1   25  2009    2009-12-05
2   80  2016    2016-03-02
```